# Wkhtmltopdf Vertical text on right hand side of every page

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, wkhtmltopdf

Below is example of PDF produced using wkhtmltopdf. I need to produce text down the right spine of the every page.  I have tried adding it to the header code put seems to clip the body of the PDF.  I am using header and footer parameters of wkhtmltopdf.  Not too sure how or if i can get this text on right hand side of every page.

[image: Example of want pdf to look like]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CSS and set the position of the element to fixed.
Try this:

```
.vertical-text {
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom auto;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works on first page when specify length in cm for top attribute.  Wonder if i can get it to repeat itself every so many cm

Comment: Thinking need to write jscript code calculates the height of the body and adds so many divs with class vertical text.  Each tag overides the top attribute.