# Rotate text and create a custom figure

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create a div like that on my twig file[image: Figure i'm trying to create]

After testing to implement this, and having tested the solutions mentioned on Stack overflow. I am stuck.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this, knowing that many CSS properties are not available with WKHTMLTOPDF

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wkhtmltopdf Vertical text on right hand side of every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489264/wkhtmltopdf-vertical-text-on-right-hand-side-of-every-page)

Comment: ^Seems to me the transform filter is usable though